# Specify ids for a migration yml file from nested json array

Tags: migrations

Given following jsons file

```
{
  "data": {
    "uuid": {
      "value": "ed64784-cjjhd6",
      "patient": false
    },
    "name": {
      "value": "Name",
      "patient": false
    },
```

how to select the **uuid** value and set it as **ids** in the migratin definition yml file?

here is my migration yml file:
I really don't know how to select the value of the uuid as **ids**

```
id: migrate_json_file
label: Migrate content from local json file
source:
  plugin: source_url
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: data/data.json

  ids:
    value:
      selector: uuid/value
      type: string
  item_selector: /data
  fields:
  - name: uuid
    label: 'uuid'
    selector: uuid

  - name: title
    label: 'title'
    selector: name


destination:
  plugin: entity:node

  process:
    type:
      plugin: default_value
      bundle: produkt

    title: name
    field_uuid: uuid

  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
    uid:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: 0

    migration_dependencies:
      required: {}
      optional: {}

    dependencies:
      enforced:
        module:
        - migration_json_file
```

Thank you in advance

Sincerely

Hermann

Comment: It looks like you may be missing the `process` section in your migration yml. Should include top level `source`, `process` and `destination`

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your reply, yes you wa right! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Hermann you're welcome. I've added the comment as an answer, so that this issue can be resolved. All the best with the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

The solution for the question:
based on the json structure I provided, I could fetch the ids using the following pattern:

```
id: migrate_json_file
label: Migrate content from local json file
source:
  plugin: source_url
  data_fetcher_plugin: file
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: data/data.json

  ids:
    **uuid**
      type: string

  item_selector: /data
  fields:
  - name: uuid
    label: 'uuid'
    **selector: uuid/value**

  - name: title
    label: 'title'
    **selector: name/value**


destination:
  plugin: entity:node

  process:
    type:
      plugin: default_value
      bundle: produkt

    title: name
    field_uuid: uuid

  sticky:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
    uid:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: 0

    migration_dependencies:
      required: {}
      optional: {}

    dependencies:
      enforced:
        module:
        - migration_json_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The migration template should include top level `source`, `process` and `destination` sections

It appears in this case you are missing the `process` section for the field value assignment there.

More info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview#etl

Comment: Hey David, your answer helped me to run the migration, although this was not the answer of my question your advice helped me avoiding getting more issues.